# How to design a Tensorflow Js model for a single output MLP?

Tags: node.js, neural-network, tensorflow.js

I am trying to implement and test a single output MLP using Tensorflow Js where my data looks like this:

`dataset = [[x_1, x_2, ..., x_n, y], ...]`

Here is my code:

```
     for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; ++i) {
         x[i] = dataset[i].slice(0, inputLength);
         y[i] = dataset[i][inputLength];
     }

     const xTrain = tf.tensor2d(x.slice(1));
     const yTrain = tf.tensor1d(y.slice(1));

     const model = tf.sequential();
     model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape: [inputLength], units: 10}));
     model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1}));
     const learningRate = 0.1;
     const optimizer = tf.train.sgd(learningRate);
     model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer});

     return model.fit(
         xTrain,
         yTrain,
         {
             batchSize: 10,
             epochs: 5
         }
     )
```

The problem is that my model is not converging and I get `null` value for loss function at each step. Also, please note that I know that I can use multivariate regression to solve this but I want to compare the result with MLP.

I was wondering if somebody can help me with this.

Comment: Are you sure `x` and `y` contain the correct values after the for loop, because it looks weird. Also `yTrain` should be two dimensional(shape:[trainingSize,1]) like `xTrain` (shape:[trainingSize,inputLength]).

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel Thanks for the reply. I am sure about that `for`, yes. Also, I tried this too:
`const xTrain = tf.tensor2d(x.slice(1), [dataset.length-1, inputLength]);`
`const yTrain = tf.tensor2d(y.slice(1), [dataset.length-1, 1]);`
still not converging.

Comment: Try reducing the learning rate

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel You are right!! I had to reduce the learning rate to `0.000000001` to make it working. I guess I need to normalize the data first and also play with the regularization values. Thanks again!

Comment: Are you ok with me putting the comment as an answer? And was the shape also causing the error?

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel Go for it please! I think the shape was part of the problem too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension of the x/y-tensors used in `model.fit()` has to be one more than the shape of the first/last layer of the model to represent multiple training data sets so GPU-accelerated batch training is possible.

Another problem of your model is the high `learningRate` (in relation to the magnitude of the training values) which prevents the model from converging because it jumps over the optimal solution and gets out of control.

Either reduce the `learningRate` or normalize the learning values to a lower magnitude.